# How to adjust width of a column to the width of the longest string in CListCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl, gdi

I am trying:

```
tstring subItemText;
    CDC* pDc = GetListCtrl().GetDC(); 
    for (int row = GetItemCount() - 1; row >= 0; --row) 
    {
      subItemText = _T("");
      for (int col = 0; col < NumCol; ++col)  
      {
        subItemText = this->GetSubItemString( GetItemData(row), col);
        CSize sz; 
        // get length of the string in logical units, by default 1 unit == 1 pixel, type of font is accounted
        sz = pDc->GetOutputTextExtent(subItemText.c_str());
        if (static_cast<int>(sz.cx) > ColWidth[col])
          ColWidth[col] = sz.cx; 
      }
    } 
    GetListCtrl().ReleaseDC (pDc);
    for (int col = 0; col < NumCol; ++col) 
    {
      SetColumnWidth(col, ColWidth[col]);
    }
```

As result width of the column is on 20/30% larger than one of the largest string in that column.
I want that width of column will be equal to width of string with max length.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you didn't select the correct font into the device context. Try this :

```
    tstring subItemText;
    CDC* pDc = GetListCtrl().GetDC(); 

    CFont *normalfont = GetListCtrl().GetFont() ;
    CFont *oldfont = pDc->SelectObject(normalfont) ;

    for (int row = GetItemCount() - 1; row >= 0; --row) 
    {
      subItemText = _T("");
      for (int col = 0; col < NumCol; ++col)  
      {
        subItemText = this->GetSubItemString( GetItemData(row), col);
        CSize sz; 
        // get length of the string in logical units, by default 1 unit == 1 pixel, type of font is accounted
        sz = pDc->GetOutputTextExtent(subItemText.c_str());
        if (static_cast<int>(sz.cx) > ColWidth[col])
          ColWidth[col] = sz.cx; 
      }
    } 

    pDc->SelectObject(oldfont) ;

    GetListCtrl().ReleaseDC (pDc);
    for (int col = 0; col < NumCol; ++col) 
    {
      SetColumnWidth(col, ColWidth[col]);
    }
```

Comment: Is your list control owner drawn ?

Comment: On line "CFont *normalfont = GetListCtrl().GetFont() ;" you must select the font that is used in the DrawItem to display the text. In my example you get the font of the list control which is not necessarily the same font that is used in Drawitem. But without seeing your code I cannot tell more.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is this:

```
SetColumnWidth(col, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE);
```

In my projects, I derive my own class from `CListCtrl` and use the following function

```
void CMyListCtrl::AutoSizeColumnWidths()
{
    // size column widths to content
    int nNumColumns = GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount();

    // for all columns ...
    for (int i = 0; i < nColumnCount; i++)
    {
        // find max of content vs header
        SetColumnWidth(i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE);
        int nColumnWidth = GetColumnWidth(i);
        SetColumnWidth(i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
        int nHeaderWidth = GetColumnWidth(i); 

        // set width to max 
        SetColumnWidth(i, max(nColumnWidth, nHeaderWidth));
    }
    SetRedraw(TRUE);
}
```

This makes sure that columns with no content still get sized according to the header text.

Comment: no I have tried it before posting my question here, this didn`t solve my issue.

Comment: @spin_eight - really? That's strange - it works fine for me - I've edited my answer to show the code I use.

Comment: I know how to use it, although thanks for code. I work with 3-rd party class, where you solution not applicable.